# Nullify the value of a column for multiple rows

Tags: sql, hana

I want to nullify a value of column for repeated rows.

**Table1**

```
Column1 column2 Column3 Measure1 
1032    45.201   091    1250
```

**Table2**

```
Column1 column2  Column3 Column4 
1032    45.2018   091       20 
1032    45.2018   091       40
```

**Query**

```
select 
A. Column1,
A. Column2,
case when B. Column4 is not null then B. Column4 else A. Column3 END AS Column 3 ,
A. Measure1,
from Table1 as A  
left outer join Table2 as B on
A.column1 = B.Column1 AND A.Column3 = B.Column3;
```

**Output**

```
Column1   column 2     Column 3    Measure1 
1032      45.2018       020         1250     
1032      45.2018       040         1250
```

**Expected output**

```
Column1   column 2     Column 3    Measure1 
1032      45.2018       020         1250     
1032      45.2018       040          0
```

How can I achieve the expected output?

Comment: column3 is different, so how come its 0? then 0 is not nullify

Comment: Use `PARTITION BY` on the relevant columns apply the `rank( )` function and set values to `0` for those lines where the rank isn't the lowest possible value, using .e.g. `CASE`. Please share the query you're using right now.

Comment: I have got column 3 with left outer join. Table 1                                                                                         Column1   column 2     Column 3   Measure1 
1032         45.2018       091          1250                                                                                 Table2    Column1   column 2     Column 3 Column4    
                1032         45.2018       091         20

Comment: Please see the code with tables and ouputs

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Row_Number`

```
SELECT A.Column1, A.Column2,
       CASE WHEN B.Column4 IS NOT NULL THEN B.Column4 ELSE A.Column3 END AS [Column3],
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER(PARTITION BY A.Column1, A.Column1, A.Measure1 ORDER BY A.Column1) = 1 
         THEN A.Measure1 ELSE 0 END AS Measure1
FROM Table1 AS A LEFT JOIN Table2 AS B ON A.column1 = B.Column1 AND A.Column3 = B.Column3;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/58982)**

**Output**

```
Column1   column 2     Column 3    Measure1 
1032      45.2018       020         1250     
1032      45.2018       040          0
```